# Do $f_n \to f$ almost surely and $0<\int f<\infty$ imply $\int f_n \to \int f$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions $f_n$ converge to $f$ almost surely and $0 < \int f < \infty$. Does this imply $\int f_n \to f$? If the condition $0 < \int f$ is removed there is many counterexamples, For example, answers for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239354/sequence-f-n-of-lebesgue-integrable-functions-which-converges-to-lebesgue?rq=1) provide some examples. All counterexamples I found are "delta function sequences", so $\int f_n < \infty$ but $f_n \to 0$ almost surely. I think that intuitively the condition $0 < \int f$ may prohibit the accumulation of the mass of $f_n$ in an infinitely small region.

EDIT.

I'm not sure but an additional condition $\int f_n$ converges could be needed. If this additional contion is actually needed, please consider it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I_{(0,1)}+nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}\to I_{(0,1)}$ almost everywhere but the integrals do not converge to the right limit. Sufficient conditions for $\lim \inf_n =\int f$ are contained in basic theorems of  measure theory: monotone convergence theorem, dominated convergence theorem etc.

Comment: Do they not converge? I think the integrals are $2$.

Comment: @rimusolem What I meant was 'integrals do not converge to the right limit'. $\int f_n \to \int f +1$.

Comment: I see. I missed an obvious example.